# Showing banner on bottom of page in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I've to show a banner `All items...` in every page. I've used `postion=fixed` here but the banner is left aligned I need it centered horizontally. Here is my code

```css
export const Bar = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.tile.backgroundColor};
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.typography.mediumFontSize};
`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the coloured part in a child div.

```html
<div class="bar">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

The bar is 100% width of the page. And the one inside is centered within that.

```css
.bar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar > div {
  margin: auto;
}
```